# Two main functions in a C application

Tags: c, makefile, build

I'm actually put in a big project. My first step to understand the code was to search the `main` function so that I have a vision of the architecture.

What I discovered is that there is more than one main function. It's true that they are in different folders, but I don't understand how this application succeed to build. What I know is that the linker expects one `main` function (Entry point).

I believe it's too hard to understand the build process of the application, so I'm asking because for sure some of you have encountered this.

1 - Should I have theoretical background to understand this?  If so, please suggest me articles, books, what ever you want.

2 - When *do* we have to use several `main` functions in one application?

Comment: Maybe they are compiled into two different binaries? Or have a mutually exclusive preprocessor guards? Or just ask the senior guy who is familiar with the code.

Comment: You _do_ have to understand the build process. The standard way is that multiple `.c` files may have multiple `main` functions (e.g. `foo.c` and `bar.c`--in different directories or not). They will generate two separate programs `foo` and `bar`. Some of the programs may be test programs or side utilities. However, you can "embed" one `main` into another with some CPP/macro trickery. In `bar.c`: `#define main bar_main`. Then, the `main` in `foo.c` can call `bar_main`. Not a great way to do it.

Comment: take a long, hard look at the makefile(s) and read the documentation for the project.  
Is it a single executable or multiple executables
Are all the files that contain a `main()` function actually included in the final executable

Comment: stackoverflow is NOT for recommending books, tutorials, etc.

Comment: If the project's build process is too complex to understand, then that's a serious liability for the project.  If it's just that you're having trouble understanding it, though, then you're experiencing what one might call "jumping in at the deep end."  It's a heck of a way to learn to swim, but effective.  Searching for `main()`s isn't a bad thing to do, but I usually start with a look at the `Makefile`(s), or their source or equivalent.

Comment: If you link two `main` functions into an executable, the linker will fail complainting about multiple `_main` definitions in the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have multiple `main` functions for a single executable. There are several possibilities.

If doing a build builds only a single application, then only one of the `main` functions will be compiled. (Or none, if there's an option to build a library rather than an executable.) There are probably options that determine which one to build, depending on which variant of the application you want, the target system, or something else.

Or perhaps the application consists of multiple executables, with one `main` function for each one.

If running the build doesn't take too long, a trick I've used to determine which of several source files is actually compiled is to temporarily add `#error` directives, like:

```
#error "TEMPORARY: This is /full/path/to/source.cpp"
```

The resulting error message will tell you which source file was actually compiled. (You can also use `#warning` directives if your compiler supports them.)

Comment: Good trick i will use it, one point, you mentioned "Or perhaps the application consists of multiple executables", when a designer have to choose multiple executable in the application, is it only for organisation stuff (it's very ugly for me) or sth else

Comment: @Mouin: One example: GNU Coreutils.

Answer (score 0):

> Should i have theorical background to undestand this, suggest me articles book what ever you want

You need to have some understanding of what a build means but, more importantly, you have to understand the build process in your specific environment. You need to have an understanding of:

1. The list of build targets (executables and shared libraries)
2. The compiler settings used by them (you could be building DLLs for VS 2010 as well as VS 2012).

> When do we have to use several main functions in one application?

1. When your build system builds multiple executables, you will need multiple `main` functions.
2. When your build system chooses file1.c or file2.c for building an executable depending on some settings, you might find `main` functions in file1.c as well file2.c. This will be a rather poor way to organize code but it is possible.

Comment: Short answer - when being put in a big project, you cannot understand nothing. You must know something. Learn, ask your peers.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to link an executable with multiple definitions for the same identifier (aka `main` in this case) will fail as the linker cannot select one or the other.

There's one possibility, though that allows you to have multiple `main` entry points, but assuring you only select one in the building process.

I'll illustrate this with a simple example: suppose you have a library (a `.a` static library) that has a module that includes a `main` definition.  As library modules are selected at link time depending on the actual need of the identifiers at the time the library is linked, you can have a `main` definition in a module to supply when you don't have one, or that module is not linked in case you have a proper definition of it.  This is exploited in some standard libraries like `-ll` (flex has a definition of main that calls the `yylex()` function), `-ly` (bison has a main definition that call the `yyparse()` routine)  These modules are included if you don't have done it before.

But beware, as if you link your main function after the library `-ll`, for example, it will be included (as `main` was not resolved at the time he library was included, and then you included the second, duplicated entry, making the `ld` linker to complaint)